# Under 18, loan possible?

Tags: united-states, loans, massachusetts, minor

I'm 17 and I got a car for dirt cheap, my mom and dad helped buy it at the time because it was a great one-time deal. The only problem is that driving school in MA is about $700 and it would really help me to get around to different clients (I do house work and miscellaneous help) and get more money in return, plus driving to school would be a huge help for my family.

Is there any way I could get a little to no interest loan with my sister (22 years old, average credit)? All I need is $700 and having my license would help me get the money back faster than without. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Guess this is really old now, but since Mike just answered I'll add a comment that I'm surprised driving school is a requirement to get a license in MA. It isn't in the 2 states that I have lived. As long as you pass the written and driving exam when required, you get your license. I taught our son to drive just so we didn't have to pay for driving school.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're a minor, this would come down to your sister lending you the money, possibly taking out a loan herself to do so.  If you can't wheedle her into doing so, then the only help she can give you is to help wheedle your parents.

Answer (score 3):

With a few exceptions that don’t apply here, minors in the US cannot be bound by any contracts they may have entered into, and can void them when they reach the age of majority. Therefore, no commercial lender will lend money to a minor, since the minor can quite legally refuse to pay back the loan. You will need to find an adult to borrow the money and give it to you, or at least co-sign on a loan. If your sister will co-sign, that should be possible, but of course she will be committing to repay the loan if you don’t.